# How to analyse a continuous data which is hetreoskedastic and is autocorrelated in R

Tags: r, regression, quantile, autocorrelation

I have data which is heteroscedastic and is autocorrelated. The predictor and response are continuous variables. Using quantreg package I can account for the heteroscedasticity but I am not sure how to account for the autocorrelation. As one of the assumptions for quantile regression is the independence of data points. Any leads will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: A similar question was raised before https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41587/quantile-regression-and-heteroscedasticity-autocorrelation

But the answers are not clear to me.

Comment: I guess it would come to down to bootstrapping as mentioned here:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38532/quantile-regression-which-standard-error-for-heteroscedasticity-serial-corre

But like the comment in the above link, any input on which bootstrap method to use will be helpful. That is if it is the only way to account for this.

Thank you.

Comment: Might be a better question for the cross-validated board?

Comment: Sure, I have posted there as well. To make it relevant to this platform, would this make sense?

How to account for spatial autocorrelation in quantile regression using quntreg package in R?